# I've create 3 additional threads in order to run 3 functions separately, but why the main thread is still running the functions?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import threading
import time

def eat_breakfast():
    time.sleep(3)
    print('You eat breakfast')

def drink_coffee():
    time.sleep(4)
    print('You drink coffee')

def study():
    time.sleep(5)
    print('You finish studying')


x = threading.Thread(target=eat_breakfast(), args=())
x.start()

y = threading.Thread(target=drink_coffee(), args=())
y.start()

z = threading.Thread(target=study(), args=())
z.start()


print(threading.active_count())
print(threading.enumerate())
print(time.perf_counter())
```

My outcome of the program is:

```
You eat breakfast
You drink coffee
You finish studying
1
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 4512423424)>]
12.034330438
```

What should I do so the program will have 4 threads running? This was just a tutorial on YouTube. The exact code works on the tutor's computer but not mine. The tutor has the outcome of 4 threads running, and 0.0756225 sec to finish the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the functions instead of passing them to the `Thread` object

```py
import threading
import time

def eat_breakfast():
    time.sleep(3)
    print('You eat breakfast')

def drink_coffee():
    time.sleep(4)
    print('You drink coffee')

def study():
    time.sleep(5)
    print('You finish studying')


x = threading.Thread(target=eat_breakfast, args=())
x.start()

y = threading.Thread(target=drink_coffee, args=())
y.start()

z = threading.Thread(target=study, args=())
z.start()


print(threading.active_count())
print(threading.enumerate())
print(time.perf_counter())
```

By passing the method names without calling them would result in a similar expected output.

Comment: Then what should I do to pass them to the thread object? Could you please type down the code. I'm sorry, I just start learning programming.

Comment: The code I provided in the answer is the one you should be using if you could not spot the difference, it is `x = threading.Thread(target=eat_breakfast(), args=())` versus `x = threading.Thread(target=eat_breakfast, args=())`, in which you should use the latter. Also make sure to check https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html it includes details regarding parameters, which should help to your learning process.

Comment: @Victoria: Short answer is leave the parentheses off the end of the `target=` argument.

Comment: oh!! I see the difference now！Thank you!